# How do I prevent the media volume from changing when a headphone is plugged in?

Tags: audio, headphones

Device: Samsung Galaxy S4
Android: Stock 4.2.2

When I listen to music with a headphone using PowerAmp, I usually set the Media volume to the max setting. *I am hard of hearing*. When I'm done, I just close PowerAmp and unplug the headphone. Then when I want to  play music again, I plug-in the headset again. At this point, I assumme the media volume setting is still at max. However, it's not. Instead, the volume has been reduced to nearly half (or at least, not max anymore).

The same behavior seems to happen even with the stock Music player.

How do I prevent the media volume from changing when a headphone is plugged in?

Answer (score 0):

Thought of using Tasker? I use it the other way. When ever I plugin my headphones, all volumes should come down irrespective of what ever value it was before.

I use Tasker to detect inserting the head phones and used an entry task to being down the volumes. I couldn't succeed sorting the volume levels before bringing it down so that I can restore them back in an exit task. Hence I restore them to a predetermined levels in the exit task.

Comment: I don't necessarily want it to be set to max. I want it to retain previous volume level. But I suppose setting it to max all the time might suffice. Will test with Tasker later.